# how to use $http in run in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to use $http for send ajax request , I write this code but i get error

```
Error: $http is not defined
```

I put this code in run

```
app.run(['$rootScope','$location','$timeout','$http', function ($rootScope,$location,$timeout,$http) {
    $rootScope.getMember = function(val){
    var persons = $rootScope.selectPerson;
    if(persons.length == 0)
        persons = null;
    return $http({
        url: 'projectTask/GetMemberForFreeTask',
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param({'searchStr':val,'selectedPerson': persons}),
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}   
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
            response.data[i]['first_name'] = response.data[i]['first_name']+' '+ response.data[i]['last_name'] 
        }
        $rootScope.states = response.data;
            return response.data
        }
    );
}
```

}])

Comment: I'm not clear what exactly you wanted to do..please elaborate more

Comment: @pankajparkar I want to send ajax request in run

Comment: why you want it in run block

Comment: If I were you, I would think very hard about why you want to code something in the Run phase of the angular application. If you set up routes then you can have your first route to initialise anything in particular.

Comment: because i want to declare three rootscope function to use it in all controllers

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the `$http` variable in your controller.

```
app.controller('TestController', function TestController($scope, $http) {
}
```

something like this. In the run method try something like this.

```
angular.module('yourApp').run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
  // do stuff here
}]);
```

Comment: i want to use it in run and send ajax request in run not in a controller

Comment: I had a similar issue and adding the variable in the run parameters worked for me. I used it like this ```angular.module('yourApp').run(function ($rootScope, $http) {...```